# Repo is unable to find a branch that exists

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

I'm trying to clone the AOSP kernel source (specially for Pixel 8), and then swap a couple projects for custom ones to build a custom kernel. 2/3 swaps work fine, but the last is giving me issues. I swapped the projects by creating a local_manifest that removes the old projects and adds my custom ones.
When running repo sync for the first time:

```
error: Cannot checkout DespairFactor/shusky: ManifestInvalidRevisionError: revision QPR2 in DespairFactor/shusky not found
error: in `sync`: revision QPR2 in DespairFactor/shusky not found
```

Which is not true. Looking at the [upstream](https://github.com/DespairFactor/shusky), we can see that QPR2 is a branch that exists.
If I just run the command a second time, the output is different, presumably because the project directory exists now:

```
error: Unable to fully sync the tree
error: Checking out local projects failed.
Failing repos:
private/devices/google/shusky
Try re-running with "-j1 --fail-fast" to exit at the first error.
================================================================================
Repo command failed due to the following `SyncError` errors:
GitCommandError: 'rev-list ^18bb05ab2b56e45f67d4c6a406c5bdb5bc546206 HEAD --' on DespairFactor/shusky failed
stderr: fatal: bad object 18bb05ab2b56e45f67d4c6a406c5bdb5bc546206
```

The commit hash it references is the latest commit on the QPR2 branch. What is going on? Why won't it sync properly? I tried manually cloning the project into the right place on the right branch, but it complains about an incorrect checkout state.

Tried: Modifying projects with new upstreams
Expected: Successful sync
Resulted: Various errors

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would be best to share these things: All the manifest files, repo version, curl version, git version and the OS version you are using. Please edit the question accordingly and update.